# Join to MSSQL table with no geom

Tags: qgis, sql-server, sql-server-spatial

I'm using QGIS 3.22.5.  I want to join an MS SQL Server (MSSQL) spatial table to an MSSQL non-spatial table.  I don't see that I can do this. Am I missing something?  Can someone tell me how to add a non-spatial MSSQL table so that I can join my spatial table to it?  If not, does anyone know why we can't add non-spatial MSSQL tables to QGIS?

Comment: The obvious easy way out is to make a view, and add that to QGIS, but from what I've seen, you can include the join in the SQL query that defines the layer (either would be faster then making an app do the join)

Comment: Thank you.  I should have been more clear that I did try creating and adding such a view.  I'll take it from your response that you've seen this work.  I've been unable to test further because I've realized I need a geometry meta table to speed up the QGIS discovery of geospatial tables in the database -- it is very slow.  Perhaps this is also causing my problem.